# SQL database won't automatically sort when updated?

Tags: mysql, sorting

Whenever I manually insert data into my sql database, it doesn't automatically resort itself. It's a minor inconvenience, but it's still there.

Also, future issue fast approaching. It's sorting numerically, but only by the first digit. At the beginning of every entry is a number, which is what I want to sort by. I'm fast approaching the hundred digit mark, which will be sorted with the tens, under the twenties based on the first digit.

Comment: A database doesn't care about order - that's purely semantic, because you could want ascending while someone else wants descending, etc.  It sounds like your table design is poor, combining what you need to be separate columns.

Comment: Don't use strings to store numeric data.  Or, when you must use strings to store numbers, use leading zeroes (or blanks) to prevent misinterpretation (and the leading zeroes give your data a pleasantly 1960s feel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "automatic sort" in a SQL database. You must specify the `ORDER BY` you desire in each query.

Data in your tables are inherently unsorted. Certain databases will order rows on disks according to a clustered index, but relying on this in the queries you write will lead to sloppy and brittle queries.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using phpMyAdmin, and you want things to be sorted each time you view a table, just do this:

1. Select the table
2. Click Operations on the top menu
3. On the top left, it says "Alter Table Order By"
4. Choose which way you want to sort it, and hit Go

Now every time you go back to that table, it will be sorted the way you chose to sort it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There's no mention of a web page or `phpAdmin` in the question. It's strictly a database question, and therefore your post doesn't answer the question asked. You might want to remove it before it starts getting downvotes. (I know that doesn't matter right now, but it might when you earn some reputation and then someone sees this wrong answer in the future.)

Comment: The point he is making is to run a query similar to: `ALTER TABLE unsorted_data ORDER BY columnA, columnB;`

Answer (score 0):

An SQL database isn't sorted -- the records are essentially in arrival order.  In order to retrieve records in sorted order you must specify a key that sorts them.

Answer (score 0):

You say it isn't sorting (as others have said, there is no native sorting behavior) but then you go on to describe how it *is* sorting, so that part of the question is a little confusing.

The sorting behavior you describe is correct. You have numbers in a text-type field, so they're being sorted lexically rather than numerically. If you want a numeric sort, you need to put that information in a field with a numeric data type, and use that in your `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as automatic sorting. You have to sort it yourself. Your problem about the sorting of numbers, Here's my solution:

```
 SELECT tbl AS(
 select CAST(SUBSTRING(<field>',1,instr(<field>',' ') as INT),<field>
 //I would then use a UNION ALL statement, something like this

 SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(<field>',1,instr(<field>',' ') as INT) as 'SortingField',<field>,A.*
 FROM <table> A
 WHERE <field> LIKE <regular expression to get fields beginning with numbers>
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 999999 as 'SortingField',<field>,A.*
 FROM <table> A
 WHERE <field> NOT LIKE <regular expression to get fields beginning with numbers>)
 ORDER BY tbl.SortingField
```

I don't have mySQL in this laptop, but i hope this helps. This has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  **ORDER BY** yourcolumn DESC // Descending
```

or

```
   *ORDER BY** yourcolumn ASC // Ascending
```